# How to get content of rendering programmatically?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I am attempting to write a method that will output the content (i.e. HTML) for any renderings that happen to exist within a specific placeholder. The goal is to pass in a `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` and the placeholder key that i'm interested in, and the method should return the rendered content.

The issue with this seems to be that there is no page context established, and therefore calling `RenderControl()` is throwing a null reference error in the `GetCacheKey()` method of the Sublayout.

Is anyone aware of a way to render a Sublayout or XSLT rendering programmatically?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
private string GetPlaceholderContent(Item item, string placeHolder)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        foreach (RenderingReference renderingReference in item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false))
        {
            if (renderingReference.Placeholder == placeHolder)
            {
                // This ensures we're only dealing with Sublayouts
                if (renderingReference.RenderingItem.InnerItem.IsOfType(Sitecore.TemplateIDs.Sublayout))
                {
                    var control = renderingReference.GetControl();
                    control.RenderControl(writer); // Throws null reference error in GetCacheKey()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Are you executing this code within a Sitecore application? So do you expect there to be a context or is it another application all-together and do you need a way to create a context manually?

Comment: Well... of course there's a way to do it... because internally this is exactly what Sitecore is doing.  I suggest some intensive exploration with ILSpy or Reflector.  Put your spelunking helmet on and then check out the renderLayout section in <pipelines>.

Comment: Maybe the option would be to add some markers around the placeholder markup and execute the request to the Item from the code and then trim the response to get only the part of the html which you're interested in?

Comment: @RuudvanFalier it is being executed within an ASMX web service that resides within my Sitecore solution. The code example I gave is wrapped in a `SiteContextSwitcher()`

Comment: @Bryan good suggestion.. I will do some digging (or spelunking as you put it).

Comment: The Item Web API is functionality to render a single rendering. Perhaps that is an avenue to explore.

Comment: Looking at it I can see that it runs the getRenderingPreview pipeline do the rendering.

Comment: @Derek - did you ever get any further with this?

Comment: @geedubb, no, sorry, I abandoned this approach after fussing with it for several days.

Comment: @Derek - thanks. I need to do something similar. I guess I will cheat and do a request for the item's page with an HTTP Request via a WebClient or similar (nasty I know, but at least everything in the pipelines config will be respected properly). There is potentially a lot to reverse engineer in the pipelines config otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

It is almost 8 years since the question was originally asked, and it turn to be [Uniform](https://uniform.dev/uniform-for-sitecore) - rendering any item/placeholder fragment!

Yes, it cuts the item you supply into placeholders/renderings:

[image]

The next step is to produce markup (for every possible data source out there):

[image]

That content is published into CDN and browser picks which version to load = personalization works!

In other words, the question you've asked turned into a cutting-edge product that **can do so much more** on top of that!

You could reverse-engineer the Uniform assemblies to see how they actually do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to programmatically render a Sublayout is to use a repeater, and put a `<sc:Sublayout>` tag in the `<ItemTemplate>`.

From there you only have to do one or both of the following:

1. Set the `DataSource` property of the `<sc:Sublayout>` to be the string representation of the desired item's GUID (i.e. the data source for the sublayout, if any)
2. Set the `Path` property of the `<sc:Sublayout>` to be the path to the Sublayout that you wish to render.

The server/sitecore will handle the rest.

Comment: This is statically inserting a sublayout in code. Derek needs to programmatically render the control in C# and have the response output string of that control in C#. He has no page context as he's in a service.