# Render a control (for an RSS feed)

Tags: rss, sitecore, rendering

I am trying to find a way of rendering a control (part of a web page) so I can add it to an RSS feed (basically `xmlns:content` before anyone gasps).

```cs
var rendering = item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Context.Device, false)
                .FirstOrDefault(it => it.RenderingID.ToString() == "{968B82C4-46D9-43F3-AD52-82AA2629156B}");

if (rendering!= null)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); // needed?
    var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    using (var wr = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        rendering.GetControl().RenderControl(wr);
}
```

What I am finding is that `sw` is empty and I was expecting it to contain html (the control displays fine on the website). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to achieve this. Sitecore runs different pipelines depending on whether this is XSL, WebForms or MVC component...

There was already a question on Stack asking same thing: [How to get content of rendering programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259830/how-to-get-content-of-rendering-programmatically) But as you can see, author abandoned the idea cause there was no way of getting this easily.